# Are "protocols" just a human alias for *nix ports?

Tags: sockets, unix, tcp, port, protocols

I'm reading the [Beej guide to network programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/syscalls.html), and I came across this

```
int getaddrinfo(const char *node,     // e.g. "www.example.com" or IP
                const char *service,  // e.g. "http" or port number
                const struct addrinfo *hints,
                struct addrinfo **res);
```

> You give this function three input parameters, and it gives you a
>   pointer to a linked-list, res, of results.
>
> The node parameter is the host name to connect to, or an IP address.
>
> Next is the parameter service, which can be a port number, like "80",
>   or the name of a particular service (found in The IANA Port List or
>   the /etc/services file on your Unix machine) like "http" or "ftp" or
>   "telnet" or "smtp" or whatever.

Are unix ports and protocols the same thing? For example `https` is the same as port `443`, and `http` is port `80`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quick**

Ports and protocols are different things, but usually protocol has default port, so default port for http protocol web server is 80.

**Explanation**

Port is tcp/ip level entity, this is endpoint where binary network requests are sent.

Protocol is application level entity, it is used as language to communicate between client and server.

Basically you can speak any protocol over any port (just make sure that server and client use the same ones). So you can speak http over 12345 port and vice versa use 80 port to speak ftp.

For example when you type in your browser stackoverflow.com - your browser first add `http://` before host name and then add `:80` after - as default port for http, so actual URL which is accessesd - http://stackoverflow.com:80/, if you type https://stackoverflow.com - browser automatically adds :443 and so on.

But if you try to open https://stackoverflow.com:80/ you will get error - as it is wrong protocol for this port.

More - you can configure your own server to use some different ports, and then you will have to indicate protocol AND port for each request, for example: `http://example.com:12345/` or `https://example.com:54321/`

Answer (score 0):

Services, such as "ftp" and "http" have default ports. In this case, 443 and 80. So they do correspond to ports. I would, however, not call them "the same thing". You could, for example, perform http protocol over a different port if you wish. When you type `http://something:8080` in your browser, for example, you are doing http over port 8080. In the case of `getaddrinfo`, it's allowing you to use the name of the service and it will internally use the default port number as determined by a configuration file (*e.g.*, `/etc/services` on some Unix systems).

Answer (score 0):

No. A port is a number, a protocol is a specification. They are associated, for convenience, but not identical.

And ports are part of TCP/IP, not Unix. The entire question is basically just a category mistake.